# Gravitational intensity of Earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, intensity

My task is to compute the gravitational intensity $E(\vec{r})$ inside Earth.

I can use the spherical symmetry of the task to use $\vec r = (r, 0, 0)$ (here $\vec r$ is inside Earth), I integrate over all points in the form of $\vec {r'} = (r', \varphi', \theta')$.

By definition,

$$E(\vec r) = A\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r \frac{r' \sin{\theta'}}{((r-r')^2 + \varphi'^2 + \theta'^2)^{3/2}}(r-r',-\varphi,-\theta)drd\varphi d\theta - A\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_r^R \frac{r' \sin{\theta'}}{((r-r')^2 + \varphi'^2 + \theta'^2)^{3/2}}(r-r',-\varphi,-\theta)drd\varphi d\theta,$$

where $A$ is a real constant and $R$ is the radius of Earth.

Is this correct? The formula is a nightmare to compute and WolframAlpha doesn't give me any solution to this.

EDIT: I was using this formula from electricity (and removed $\varrho$ from the integral, because it is constant):

$$\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\varrho} \int_S \frac{\sigma(\boldsymbol{r}^\prime)}{{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^\prime|}^3}(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^\prime)\mathrm{d}V$$

Comment: Your formula is incorrect: in the denominator, $(r-r')^2$ is the square of a length but not $\varphi'^2$ and $\theta'^2$. Moreover, $drd\varphi d\theta$ is not the correct volume element in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake copying the formula I came up with. I also explained where I derived it from. I am not sure, but I think the "wrong units" comment would also apply to the electricity formula?

Comment: If you are going to borrow from electricity, how about using Gauss's law.  That would permit a mass density that varies with the radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cartesian coordinates, the difference between two vectors $\vec r=\pmatrix{x & y & z}$ and $\vec r'=\pmatrix{x' & y' & z'}$ is simply given by
$$\vec r'-\vec r=\pmatrix{x'-x & y'-y & z'-z}$$
so that
$$||\vec r'-\vec r||^2=(x'-x)^2+(y'-y)^2+(z'-z)^2$$
However, you cannot do the same with spherical coordinates. Note that $x'-x$, $y'-y$ and $z'-z$ are lengths, which is not the case of $\varphi$ and $\theta$. In spherical coordinates, one should use the fact that
$$||\vec r'-\vec r||^2=(\vec r'-\vec r).(\vec r'-\vec r)
    =r'^2+r^2-2\vec r.\vec r'$$
If you choose $\vec r$ along the $z$-axis ($\theta=0$), then the angle between $\vec r$ and $\vec r'$ is $\theta'$ (easy to see on a figure). Therefore,
$$||\vec r'-\vec r||^2=r'^2+r^2-2rr'\cos\theta'$$
In spherical coordinates, the volume element is
$$d^3\vec r'=dr'\times r'd\theta'\times r'\sin\theta' d\varphi'$$
(the product of three infinitesimal lengths). The gravitational field is
$$\vec G=-\rho\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^R {(\vec r-\vec r')\over ||\vec r-\vec r'||^3}d^3\vec r'$$
To simplify the calculation, you should use the symmetry of the mass distribution of the Earth (assumed to be spherical) to show that the gravitational field is along the $z$-axis (and therefore along $\vec r$). It is then sufficient to compute the component
$$G_z={\vec G.\vec r\over r}
   =-{\rho\over r}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^R {r^2-rr'\cos\theta'\over [r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta']^{3/2}}r'^2dr'\sin\theta'd\theta'd\varphi'$$

This is the hardest way to compute the gravitational field inside the earth. The integral is a bit easier if you compute the gravitational potential instead of the gravitational field. Applying the Gauss law is by far the simplest way to compute the gravitational field of a sphere.

Comment: Thank you, I can see the mistake now. But when I have $\vec r = (0, 0, r)$ inside the Earth, I should be integrating up to $z$, not $R$, right? What about the rest of the Earth pulling the other way?

Comment: You don't have to distinguish the two cases: the direction of gravitational field created by the mass in the volume element $d^3\vec r'$ is always in the direction of $-(\vec r-\vec r')$. The sign of the projection onto the z-axis changes appropriately.